# LineageID is string or Integer

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm trying to fetch lineageId of output columns in a SSIS Package. I'm traversing SSIS Package as XML Document in C# code.

No issue in traversing and fetching data from the nodes in the package, but facing issue when I'm trying to fetch LineageID.

I many forums and articles said that LineageId generated in SSIS Package is a Unique Integer value for that particular package, so I'm trying to convert LineageID to an integer value. But it seems to be a String value.

Kindly clarify my doubt. Is lineageid STRING OR INT?

If it is Int then please tell me how to find it.

```
foreach (var x in NodeCollection)
        {
    var outputCollection = x.Elements("outputColumn");
            foreach (var output in outputCollection)
            {
                string Name = output.Attribute("name").Value;
                long LineageId = Convert.ToInt64(output.Attribute("lineageId").Value);
            }
        }
```

By debugging with Breakpoint "output.Attribute("lineageId").Value" is returning following value

"Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[TYPE]"

Answer (score 0):

I have performed a very similar exercise and found that the lineage id values were definitely integer. This is an extract from my code:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts");
foreach (XmlNode childnode in doc.SelectNodes("//*[@lineageId != '' and @name != '']"))
    {
        XmlNode ExecutableNode = childnode.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::DTS:Executable[1]", nsmgr);
        var taskName = ExecutableNode.SelectSingleNode("DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='ObjectName']", nsmgr).InnerText;
        var targetColumnName = childnode.Attributes["name"].Value;
        var lineageID = Convert.ToInt32(childnode.Attributes["lineageId"].Value);
```

We are using this to map column names to lineageid's so that we can interpret error messages thrown by our SSIS packages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you please upload a sample pkg with your code? I am trying to implement this is SSIS but I keep getting "Input string was not in a correct format." error and just like the OP, I too get a string value for the LineageID field...
I not able to get the error column name in SSIS 2012...
Thx